# Shared subfolder not accessible over network unless parent folder is also Shared

Tags: windows-xp, file-sharing, windows-networking

I've got a Media folder with a Music subfolder:
Server\Media\Music

If I share Music, it's not accessible over the network ( via \server\media\music )
If I also Share Media, then Music is accessible.

Server is Windows XP sp3 and have tried accessing it from Windows 7 an Windows XP computers.
I've tried it with Simple File Sharing and without.

Is this just a(weird!) bug?

Comment: Have you tried going to the path directly?

Comment: I tried going directly to \\server\media\music (that's how I tested it). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yup, just checking

Answer (score 0):

All shares should be available at the top level. Ie, if you share "c:\media\music" over the network it should show up as \server\music not \server\media\music. You should also make sure permissions on the tree leading to the shared folder allow the users connecting in to view or get to that folder. Shared folders use two permissions sets: the permissions on the underlying file system, and the permissions on the share itself. Simple folder sharing however should reduce it down to just the share permissions. Should. :D

Comment: Yes, teh shares are available directly (\\server\media  and \\server\music).  Permissions for Everyone and Users are the same for both folders.

Comment: i've done things like this before and not seen this problem. are we sure the folder on-disk is named what we think it is? sometimes explorer likes to use desktop.ini to internally rename things? (eg "Documents" in win7 sometimes becomes "My Documents" in explorer's view...)